# iOS and macOS synching messages, but old messages not restoring on Mac

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I have been an iPhone user for a while, but just recently got back into the macOS game.  I have configured Messages to synch with iCloud and messages are syncing.  It was my intention, and half the reason I got this wee MacBook, to be able to view and search my old messages more nimbly.  With syncing, am I not supposed to be getting my old messages too?  Is this a known issue?  Is there a manual way to transfer the history and then resume syncing the conventional way?

Answer (score 1):

So I must be impatient..sort of.  I had to connect/logout/reconnect to iCloud several times in different ways with my Mac and my phone.  It's finally downloading...ahhhh. It is a bit wonky tbh.